# Reverse lookup object with array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

Let say if I have an object like this

```
resourceMap = {
    "a": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    "b": [11, 12],
    "c": [21, 23],
    "d": [54, 55, 56, 57, 510]
};
```

What is the best way to figure out if `resourceId = 21` would be `"c"`?

We don't know the key names or number of keys. It only matches once: meaning `21` will belong to only one key `"c"`.

I am thinking of looping through all keys and do `indexOf()`, but I don't feel it's "elegant" enough.

I could use Underscore but try to avoid and go with what Angular or jQuery or just vanilla Javascript.

Comment: Are the numbers in the arrays distinct, or is it possible that a number reverse-maps to more than a single item?

Comment: Either you pre-process it to be in a different format or you loop on demand. Either way Vanilla JS or underscore, you will end up doing the same thing under the covers.

Comment: @spender says it right in the OPs question. *"It only matches once:..."*

Comment: @spender the number only occurs once in each key or in all the keys.

Comment: Why is there "JSON" in the header?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's perfectly acceptable to have [numeric property names for objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals) in JavaScript. We can use this to our advantage to build a second object that maps everything in reverse. This will make lookups inexpensive.

```
var reverseMap = {};
for(var propName in resourceMap)
{
    var numsArr = resourceMap[propName];
    numsArr.forEach(function(num){
        reverseMap[num]=propName;
    });
}
console.log(reverseMap[54]); //'d'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y11sbgbv/

Building the reverseMap can also be done more "functionally" (e.g. without using side-effects) as follows:

```
var reverseMap2 = Object.keys(resourceMap).reduce((acc, propName) =>          
  resourceMap[propName].reduce((a, num) => {
    a[num] = propName;
    return a;
  }, acc), {});
```

Answer (score 3):

Preprocess into a different look up table

```
var revMap = []; // or var revMap = {};
Object.keys(resourceMap).forEach(function(key) { 
    resourceMap[key].forEach( function (ind) {
         revMap[ind] = key;   
    });
});
console.log(revMap[21])
```

or look up on demand:

```
resourceMap = { "a": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], "b": [11, 12], "c": [21, 23], "d": [54, 55, 56, 57, 510] };
function findMapKey (map, ind) {
    var match = null;
    Object.keys(map).some(function(key) {
        var test = map[key].indexOf(ind)!==-1;
        if (test) { 
            match = key; 
        } 
        return test;
    });
    return match;
}
console.log(findMapKey(resourceMap, 21));
```

Comment: `Object.keys`... didn't know about that. +1 , although the sparseness of arrays is an implementation detail that I wouldn't rely on. Given that numeric property names are fine, I'd use an object over an array for the map.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're working with a massive amount of data, your idea is fine:

```js
    var resourceMap = {
      "a": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
      "b": [11, 12],
      "c": [21, 23],
      "d": [54, 55, 56, 57, 510]
    };

    /**
     * @return resource's group, or false if no matching group is found
     */
    var getResourceGroup = function(res) {
      for (var i in resourceMap) {
        if (resourceMap[i].indexOf(res) > -1) {
          return i;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }

    console.log(getResourceGroup(21));
```

I understand the desire for elegance, and I strive for that in my own work as well.  But this is simple, easily supported, and relatively fast assuming your data set isn't huge.

If you're going to call the function multiple times, it might be worth building out the reverse dictionary the first time through the function, so that you can use that to speed up future lookups.  The catch there is that if you *do* have a ton of data, you're going to build a fairly large data structure in memory. Probably not a big deal, but worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like values are sorted, so you can first look if the latest of each array is greater than the value you're searching for, once you find it, look for the value itself.

```
for(var propName in resourceMap)
{
    var array = resourceMap[propName];
    var lastNum = array[array.length-1];

    if(lastNum == 21 || (lastNum > 21 && array.indexOf(21) > -1))
    {
       console.log(propName)
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you're going to do searches on it often, then go with spender answer

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
resourceMap = {
    "a": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    "b": [11, 12],
    "c": [21, 23],
    "d": [54, 55, 56, 57, 510]
};

var getKey = function(val, _key) {
$.each(resourceMap, function(k, v) {
  if ($.inArray(val, v) != -1) {
    _key = k
  }  
})
return _key
};

getKey(21)
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/gbnzmq51/